# Is there a nice expression for the Fourier transform of a dot product of two functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose we have two vectors $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we wish to take the Fourier transform of their dot product, that is, we wish to evaluate

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{A(x) \cdot B(x) \}.
\end{equation}

My question is is there a nice expression for this in terms of the Fourier transforms of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$?

So far I have determined that if we let $A(x) = (a_1, a_2, \dotsc , a_n) $ and similarly for $B(x)$, this can be written as the sum of the convolutions of individual elements

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{A(x) \cdot B(x) \} = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathcal{F}\{a_j\} \star\mathcal{F}\{b_j\},
\end{equation}

but ideally I would prefer to write this in terms of the FTs of the vectors themselves. I suspect there might not be a nicer expression, but I am very rusty with FTs and convolutions and my googling skills are not turning up anything useful.

(As an aside, the reason I am interested in this is I wish to find the FT of the poisson bracket of two functions which I am writing as

\begin{equation}
\{H, \rho\} = \nabla H \cdot \Omega \nabla \rho
\end{equation}

so if anyone knows any specific results about FTs of poisson brackets that might also be of help.)

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. The dot product of two functions is a number, no?

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about the dot product of two vectors A(x) and B(x) in R^n, the result is still just a number but I was hoping to find a nice result in terms of the FTs of the vectors A and B. Maybe im misunderstanding your question?

Comment: How do you Fourier transform a number?

Comment: Ok they are both functions of x so its not 'just a number' its a function. I thought you were asking if it was a scalar or not.

Comment: the dot product is not a function of $x$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say here. Could you possibly expand on what you are getting at.

Comment: I'm sorry. Usually 'dot product' is taken to mean 'inner product'. What you mean I think is 'pointwise product' or just 'product'. The Fourier transform of the product is the convolution of the individual transforms.

Comment: No, I mean the inner product. I feel like you aren't understanding my question at all.

Comment: I think the expression you have is the best you are going to get, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the dot-convolution of vector valued functions as
$$
u\,\dot{\star}\,v := \int u(x-y)\cdot v(y)\,\mathrm d y =  \sum_{j=1}^n u_j\star v_j.
$$
Then your expression can be written as
$$
\mathcal F(u\cdot v) = \mathcal F(u)\,\dot{\star}\,\mathcal F(v).
$$
At the end, this is just notations. Some papers even write just $uv$ instead of $u\cdot v$, so that this becomes really like the classical convolution of scalars.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the dot-product is the Euclidean inner product, you could apply the convolution theorem to each component, i.e. $F(A\cdot B) = F(\sum_i A_i B_i) = \sum_i F(A_i)*F(B_i)$, where $*$ means convolution, $F$ means Fourier transform, and subscripts indicate components of the vectors.

This may not be easier to compute than the original form in some cases.